# How to use __call__?

Tags: python

For example, I need for class calling returns string.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'bar'

    def __call__(self):
        return self.bar
```

`Foo` calling returns `Foo object`.

```
Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x8ff6a8c>
```

What should I do to class returns string or other? How to use `__call__`?

Comment: `Foo()()` would work too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your example (of limited usefulness), you have a class of callable objects.

You can do now, as you have done,

```
>>> o = Foo()
>>> o
<__main__.Foo object at 0x8ff6a8c>
>>> o()
'bar'
```

I. e., `__call__()` does not make your class callable (as it is already), but it gives you a callable object.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, everything is an object. *Even classes*.

Classes, furthermore, are callable objects. You don't have to do anything to make this happen, they just are. Calling the class creates an instance.

Setting up a `__call__` method makes the instances also callable. You call the instances the same way you called the class (or any other function).

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print "init"
   ...:         
   ...:     def __call__(self):
   ...:         print "call"
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [2]: a = A()
init

In [3]: a()
call
```